# Can you have more than 3 active JavaFX media players?

Tags: java, javafx, media-player

I have the following code:

```
//Static holder to prevent mediaplayer being garbage collected
static MediaPlayer MediaPlayerHolder;

@FXML
private void PlaySong() throws IOException {
    //Load file into media player
    try {
        String Path = "SOME FILE PATH";
        Media media = new Media(Path);
        MediaPlayer mediaplayer = new MediaPlayer(media);

        //I think this is necessary to stop the mediaplayer being garbage collected??
        MediaPlayerHolder = mediaplayer;

        mediaplayer.setOnReady(() -> mediaplayer.play());

        mediaplayer.setOnEndOfMedia(() -> mediaplayer.dispose());

    } catch(Exception e){}
}
```

I can call the function as many times as I like but when it is called for the fourth time the first playing instance stops before the next starts. I have tried removing the static reference bit but then the player is stopped about 2 seconds after it starts playing.

Is there any way I can have more than 3 media players playing at the same time?

Comment: Isn't this just the same problem you've already noticed: the media players are going out of scope and getting gc'd? You only hold a reference to the last one created.

Comment: @James_D I have tested this and you are correct. Massive oversight on my part. Thanks!

Comment: Presumably you're going to introduce some controls at some point which, e.g., allow the user to stop each media player. The event handlers for those controls will require a reference to the media player, which will solve the problem...

Comment: java naming conventions please!

Comment: @James_D that’s the plan, thanks for the help.

Comment: @kleopatra On it!